# How to relate interior points to a discrete metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to grasp the concept of *metric spaces*, particularly, *discrete metric spaces*. I would like to provide an example of **interior points** in a *discrete metric space*, but am not sure what this entails. If anyone could provide an example of interior points for **any (of your choosing)** *discrete metric space*, or proof that none exist, I would greatly appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every discrete metric space we have that every set is both open and closed, so in particular if $E \subseteq X$ is a subset of a discrete metric space $X$, then every point in $E$ is an interior point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space

So any set is open, in particular any set is equal to its interior.